# SDL2 MOUSEBUTTONUP triggers more then once

Tags: events, mouseevent, sdl-2

I've been trying to figure this out all day. I'm trying to make a simple check box. But my MOUSEBUTTONUP event keeps firing until I trigger another event like moving the mouse or clicking again.

```
//If a mouse button was released
    if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
    {
        //If the left mouse button was pressed
        if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            //Get the mouse offsets
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);

            //If the mouse is over the button
            if ((mouseX > Button->GetX()) && (mouseX < Button->GetX() + Button->GetWidth()) && (mouseY > Button->GetY()) && (mouseY < Button->GetY() + Button->GetHeight()))
            {
                    //Set the button sprite
                    state = selected;
                    Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                    clicked = true;
                    std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will just spam 1 in the console (if you dont move the mouse) when all I want is for it to trigger once. From what I've read MOUSEBUTTONUP is only supposed to be sent to the event queue once

I've tried adding a bool to stop it after it's clicked by putting it in an if statement and that works but the thing is I want to be able to toggle the box on and off so when I add an else statement that changes the bool back to false it spams 101010 instead of just one.

```
        //If a mouse button was released
    if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
    {
        //If the left mouse button was pressed
        if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            //Get the mouse offsets
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);

            //If the mouse is over the button
            if ((mouseX > Button->GetX()) && (mouseX < Button->GetX() + Button->GetWidth()) && (mouseY > Button->GetY()) && (mouseY < Button->GetY() + Button->GetHeight()))
            {
                if (clicked == false)
                {
                    //Set the button sprite
                    state = selected;
                    Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                    clicked = true;
                    std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Set the button sprite
                    state = noInteraction;
                    Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                    clicked = false;
                    std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It appears your `Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()` returns latest event. It is likely you'll need a way to reset it to 'invalid' state.

Comment: @keltar That was it! Totally makes sense. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In `Sdl_Setup` is where I make the window I'm using and stuff like that and the variable `mainEvent` is `= new SDL_Event();` so then when I was calling `GetMainEvent()` it was just sending that to `PollEvent()` over and over again. So all I did is create a quick `void` function in `Sdl_Setup` to set `mainEvent` to a blank `SDL_Event()` and then call that after `clicked = true;` and it works.